# Formatting generated data

Tags: c, text

I generated data - 1000 rows, used https://www.mockaroo.com

```
Matthew,Richards,2/2/1992,mrichards0@sbwire.com,86-(493)702-4682,0284 Artisan Avenue
Arthur,Myers,5/30/1959,amyers1@globo.com,56-(105)354-8682,5 Center Hill
Stephanie,Hayes,8/6/1976,shayes2@cdc.gov,62-(945)765-1251,979 Aberg Parkway
Lisa,Reynolds,5/10/1956,lreynolds3@i2i.jp,256-(450)430-9937,8 Aberg Terrace
Kathleen,Gonzales,12/11/1971,kgonzales4@sciencedirect.com,86-(745)695-8094,520 Basil Court
...
...
...
```

Now I need to add this to an array in C, so I want it to look like this:

```
{"Matthew","Richards","2/2/1992","mrichards0@sbwire.com","86-(493)702-4682","0284 Artisan Avenue"},
{"Arthur","Myers","5/30/1959","amyers1@globo.com","56-(105)354-8682","5 Center Hill"},
...
...
...
```

Do you know how to add quotes and braces? Is there and app/program which could do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open up your favorite text editor such as MS Word, Notepad++, Sublime Text, Atom, etc... even Notepad that comes with windows can do this

look for a find and replace option. (usual Ctrl + F does it), it's also usually under "Edit" on the menu bar.

replace all `,` with `","`